# Criar links de "esqueci a senha" em Android

Tags: android

Olá, alguém sabe como faço para criar um botão de link para redefinir senha como o da imagem abaixo, e quando for clicado abrir outra Activity?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem duas opções que resolvem o seu problema, são elas: você pode utilizar um `Button` ou uma `TextView`.

> **Button**

O primeiro, que é o mais comum a ser utilizado, você deve ter se deparado com o problema dele ter um `background`, mas, felizmente, resolver isto também é possível. Você pode substituir o background dele por um outro que já é padrão do android. Primeiro, você vai precisar definir um **estilo** para o seu botão, e esse estilo vai definir como ele irá se comportar em seu layout. No seu caso, como um botão sem background, mas sem perder os efeitos que um botão tem.

```
<Button
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

O código acima nos mostra 2 importantes **atributos**, que são eles `style` e `background`.
O atributo `style` está apontando para uma **resource** que está presente na plataforma do Android, ou seja, todas as APIs terão esta resource, e para cada API, ela será diferente. No android L ela tem um comportamento diferente, assim como no Holo ela também tem outro comportamente.

O mesmo serve para o atributo `background`, com o `selectableItemBackground`. Ele te oferece um efeito de clique (o **ripple effect**). Existem outras opções que você pode utilizar, que são `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, é praticamente a mesma coisa, mas os efeitos de cliquem se dispersam, porque é como se o botão não tivesse bordas.

Você também pode sublinhar o texto do seu botão, se caso precisar:

```
forgotPassword.setPaintFlags(forgotPassword.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

> **TextView**

Já que o botão herda da classe **TextView**, isto significa que tudo que você fez com o botão pode ser feito com esta classe. Ou seja, podemos aplicar o estilo e o background da mesma forma.

```
<TextView
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Como você pode ver, é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas com uma exceção, há um atributo chamado `clickable`. Ele apenas aponta para o sistema que esta view pode ser clicada e isto faz com que ela execute os efeitos de clique, se caso ela tiver um `onClickListener`, você pode remover este atributo.

Se quiser deixar o texto sublinhado, é a mesma coisa

```
forgotPassword.setPaintFlags(forgotPassword.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Como você pode ver, o uso vai depender de você. Mas eu recomendo  que você utilize um `Button`, já que é algo padrão.

**Obs**: ao utilizar o `borderlessButtonStyle` em um botão, o atributo background pode ser removido, já que ele se comportará normalmente... como um botão sem bordas e sem background, por causa do estilo atribuído a ele.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisar primeiro declarar o textview no seu código:

```
Textview telaperdeusenha = (Textview ) findviewbyid(R.id.telaperdeusenha);
```

depois você cria um evento de click no textview e envia pra outra activity

```
textviewperdeusenha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent telaperdeusenha = new Intent(this, telaperdeusenha.class);               
            startActivity(telaperdeusenha);

        }
    });
```